# How do you append a carriage return to a value in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

I'm importing some restaurant information and have found that I'm missing the type of cuisine in the description field.  How do I append a carriage return to a value?

This is what I have so far; I want the cuisine to go in on a new line:

```
select concat(field_id_20, '\r', 'french') from table
```

Comment: Why dont you do the select first, assign it to a variable and then do the manipulation?

Comment: why can I not use a WHERE clause with this?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

If you want a new line, then you're looking for a `\n` newline rather than a carriage return.

```
SELECT CONCAT_WS('\n', field_id_20, 'french');
```

[`CONCAT_WS()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat-ws) concatentates all subsequent arguments with the first argument. So you could add multiple lines this way by doing:

```
SELECT CONCAT_WS('\n', field_id_20, 'french', 'german', 'indian');

Outputs:

CurrentValueFrom field_id_20
french
german
indian
```

Comment: is there anyway i can verify this is what it's doing in the results window?  Because it just all looks like it's on the same line...

Comment: @jeff What OS/client are you using? On a standard command line MySQL client, I see the line breaks correctly.

Comment: i'm a bit of a mysql noob, I'm used to SQL Server!

Comment: @jeff Yeah, IIRC Workbench displays rows as, well, rows, without interpreting line breaks. I don't have it installed, but I thought it had a way to display results as plain text, in which you should see the line breaks.  You should take the time to familiarize yourself with the command line `mysql` client. It's often faster to work in than Workbench for small tasks.

Comment: I know this is from a long time ago, but in workbench you can right click the result and select 'Open Value in Viewer' to see how it would be formatted