# Adding json to new line

Tags: php, sql-server, json

I am using MSSQL localDb with PHP for creating json to show json data on javascript.

But label's text shown as **"blaaa \n blaa"**  My basic codes as below;

MSSQL

```
SELECT field1 + ' \n ' + filed2 FROM table1
```

PHP Script

```
....    
$PdoStatement=$PdoObject->prepare($SqlQuery);
$PdoStatement->execute();
$PdoResultToArray=$PdoStatement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$JsonPdoResultArray = array("Datas"=>$PdoResultToArray);
$Json=json_encode(array_merge($JsonSystemArray, $JsonPdoResultArray));
echo $Json;
```

Answer (score 1):

you could make it like this

```
SELECT CONCAT_WS('\n', field1, filed2) as concatenatedFeild FROM table1
```

and when you need to use it you call this

`concatenatedFeild`

see this also it could help a lot

[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9314689/how-do-you-append-a-carriage-return-to-a-value-in-mysql)

**UPDATE**

```
SELECT (field1 + CHAR(13) + field2) as concatenatedFeild from table1
```

Comment: Thank you very much too. But  showing such as "blaaa\nblaa"

Comment: I am using Appcelerator for client. I am checking result from it.

Comment: @Kerberos so what happen ?

Comment: I am using MSSQL "CONCAT_WS" is not working on it. <br> is not working too on client side :(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/99072/discussion-between-alaa-m-jaddou-and-kerberos).

Comment: see the update please and [check this](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/sqlserver/en-US/c4257e88-87db-4d2b-8a5e-fd27c4c413ff/how-to-add-new-line-in-select-statement)

Comment: Ibrahim give me same suggest but that wasn't worked too.

Comment: @Kerberos try it with ('field1' + '\n' + 'field2') or 'field1' + '\n' + 'field2' i think this will work

Comment: I solved my problem and wrote as answer. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

I solved my problem as below,

MSSQL

```
SELECT CONCAT(field1, '_Newline_', filed2) AS ConcatedFiled FROM table1
```

PHP

```
....
$JsonPdoResultArray = array("Datas"=>$PdoResultToArray);
$Json=json_encode(array_merge($JsonSystemArray, $JsonPdoResultArray));
$Json = str_replace("_Newline_","\\n", $Json);
echo $Json;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try concatenating with `char(13)` like so:
`SELECT field1 + char(13) + filed2 FROM table1`

Comment: Thank you very much but result is same :( showing such as "blaaa blaa" new line is not showing

Comment: But in the PHP script does the new line appear? Or a \n when you concatenated with char(13)? Maybe the problem is somewhere else, not in the query but in the app or in the code.

Comment: I solved my problem and wrote as answer. Thank you for your help.